# Simple array not stepping through

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int i;
int b = 0;
int a[20];


for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
a[i] = b+1;
cout << a[i];}



 }
```

//I know this is a simple program but it is not giving the expected output and does not step through the program or print out the result

Comment: what is your expected output? The answer would just be 1, 20 times. if you want it to increment you will have to add b+=1 and then a[i] = b;

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Comment: It should print out 1-20 correct?

Comment: @user2420948: No.  You're no modifying `b`, you're assigning its current value + 1 to a[0...20].

Comment: so simple gahhh anyone recommend a good c++ book?

Comment: The curly braces in this code sample do not appear to match, so I'm assuming that something's missing here. Can you post the rest of the program's source code, or is the program too lengthy to fit on this page?

Answer (score 3):

Your loop keeps assigning `a[i]` without changing `b`. Since `b` stays at zero, all `a`s are going to be `1` (because `b` is zero, `b+1` is `1`).

If you would like to assign sequential values, either use the loop index `i`, or change `b` in the body of the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    a[i] = i+1;
}
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    a[i] = ++b; // Adds 1 to b, and changes b for the next iteration.
}
```

Comment: for some reason it still did not work even with these corrections? Still getting random output

Comment: @user2420948 Something else must be wrong then: here is a [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/DSjMeX) showing your program producing correct results.

Comment: @user2420948 Perhaps you forgot to add `<< endl` at the end of your output, so the numbers appear to be glued together?

Comment: im using visual studio 2012 which ide are you using?

Comment: @user2420948 I use the online IDE service "ideone.com". Did you follow the link in my comment above?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the wrong variable. This should work:

```
int i;
int a[20];


for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
a[i] = i+1;
cout << a[i];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you want it assign through `b` :

```
int i;
int b = 1;
int a[20];



for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
a[i] = b;
cout << a[i];
b++;}
```